# Find out the changed file names and (added) line numbers

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I need to get

1. the changed **files names**
2. for every added line, its **line number**

E.g. given [this](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc5894bc720596964f65f2f645752d4740dbb731) commit, I want to get *compat/unsetenv.c* and *5,6,7*.

I was trying to use

```
git show <commit-id>
```

and do some dirty string matching on it. I can get away with a

```
| grep +++
```

for the file name,  but I found no way of making git show the line number next to the + sign, as in the GitHub web interface.

Is there any other way to find the (added) line numbers?

Comment: `git blame` shows line numbers.  Will that work?

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers

Comment: Thank you @CarlNorum for putting me on the right track: `git blame --porcelain <filename> | grep <id> | awk '{print $2}'` does the job. It still feels like a messy way of doing it, but as long as it works...

Comment: you shoul try:

git diff --stat