# How can I add a shell function in git alias with pipe

Tags: git, alias

I found an good shell function **diff-lines()** from [Using git diff, how can I get added and modified lines numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers/12179492#12179492)

I'v add the function in my `.bashrc` file, and it works in my commandline:

```
[marslo@mppdev ~/Tools/Git/LinuxStuff]
$ git diff -U0 | diff-lines
Scripts/.marslorc:29:-# Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers
Scripts/.marslorc:29:+# Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers/12179492#12179492
```

However, when I tried to add the command as a git alias, here something wrong:

```
[marslo@mppdev ~/Tools/Git/LinuxStuff]
$ cat ~/.gitconfig | grep "ldiff ="
    ldiff = "!bash -c 'git diff -U0' | diff-lines"
[marslo@mppdev ~/Tools/Git/LinuxStuff]
$ git ldiff
sh: diff-lines: command not found
fatal: Failed to run 'bash -c 'git diff -U0' | diff-lines' when expanding alias 'ldiff'
```

And, `bash -c 'git diff -U0' | diff-lines` still works

```
[marslo@mppdev ~/Tools/Git/LinuxStuff]
$ bash -c 'git diff -U0' | diff-lines
Scripts/.marslorc:29:-# Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers
Scripts/.marslorc:29:+# Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers/12179492#12179492
```

Here the details:
[image: ldff]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `diff-lines` is a shell function and not an actual executable.  When you run `"!bash -c 'git diff -U0' | diff-lines"` you get an error because the shell is not sourcing your `~/.bashrc` and so it does not know about `diff-lines`.  This is normal behavior for shells--they only source those settings in specific circumstances, and running a command is not one of them.

So here are a few recommendations.  First, if the line number feature is nice outside of git, consider making diff-lines a script instead of just a shell function:

```
#!/bin/bash

diff-lines() {
    local path=
    local line=
    while read; do
        esc=$'\033'
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ---\ (a/)?.* ]]; then
            continue
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ \+\+\+\ (b/)?([^[:blank:]$esc]+).* ]]; then
            path=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ @@\ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\ \+([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\ @@.* ]]; then
            line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^($esc\[[0-9;]+m)*([\ +-]) ]]; then
            echo "$path:$line:$REPLY"
            if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != - ]]; then
                ((line++))
            fi
        fi
    done
}

diff-lines
```

You can then set your alias to be:

```
ldiff = !sh -c 'git diff "$@" | diff-lines' -
```

This will also allow you to pass parameters to `git ldiff`, just like the real diff command.  You could also use `diff-lines` as your pager by doing the following in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[pager]
    diff = diff-lines | less
```

Then, the regular `git diff` command will be piped through your `diff-lines` script and finally through less to get the paging.  I use that same trick to highlight words changes in lines.

Another option is what Adam mentioned: create a script called `git-ldiff` that runs your diff command and pipes it through diff-lines

```
#!/bin/bash

diff-lines() {
    local path=
    local line=
    while read; do
        esc=$'\033'
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ---\ (a/)?.* ]]; then
            continue
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ \+\+\+\ (b/)?([^[:blank:]$esc]+).* ]]; then
            path=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ @@\ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\ \+([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\ @@.* ]]; then
            line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^($esc\[[0-9;]+m)*([\ +-]) ]]; then
            echo "$path:$line:$REPLY"
            if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != - ]]; then
                ((line++))
            fi
        fi
    done
}

git diff "$@" | diff-lines
```

Note: this is exactly the same script as above with a small modification to the last line.

Comment: Hi @jszkmeister, diff-lines cannot be set at the end of `.bashrc`. Otherwise, the bash always waiting for read when I open a terminal.

Comment: Hi, I tired all your method, they all cannot work except create a new script and add the location to $PATH. Is there any way to alias without create a new file? Thanks

Comment: @MarsloJiao As I said in the post, you would need to make diff-lines a script--that's the best way of doing this.  There are other choices, but I'm consider them subpar for various reasons.  You could, for example, source your .bashrc manually or force a login shell.  The first choice would look something like this: `ldiff = !bash -c '. ~/.bashrc && git diff "$@" | diff-lines' -`.  You could also do: `ldiff = !bash -l -c 'git diff "$@" | diff-lines' -` to make it a login shell (which will read your `~/.bashrc`).  The best option is to create a script though.

Comment: Oh yeah!!!! It works!! The alias is exactlly `ldiff = !bash -c '. ~/.bashrc && git diff "$@" | diff-lines' -`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, I have a question, .bashrc will be executed while I login. And it actually works (I can use diff-lines in command line). Why this file needs be source again?

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's wrong. Thanks for your patience. Your answers helped me pretty much!!

Comment: And, actually, much great outside of git can be using now. :). Here is `git info` https://gist.github.com/subtleGradient/6731, the script has been added into `.bashrc`, my alias just looks like `info = !bash -l -c 'gitinfo'`. Pretty cool!!

Comment: @MarsloJiao You're welcome.  Just be careful of what you put in your `.bashrc`.  If you start interacting with the screen or user, you'll break every command that does this trick.  That's why it's not a good idea.  You could stash all the git-related shell functions into a `~/.gitrc` and source it from your `.bashrc` and from your aliases.  That would at least protect you from such an issue.  Glad you've got things working.  :-)

Comment: HAHAHA, that's exactlly what I've done. I create a file named `.marslorc`, and sourced it in `.bashrc`(much bashrcs using by me). The separate script is good for maintenance. The purpose of *scripts added in `.bashrc`* just for quick understanding, :). [This](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/master/HOME/.marslo/.marslorc) is **.marslorc**, and [This](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/tree/master/HOME/.marslo) is **.bashrcs**; [This](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/master/HOME/Git/.gitconfig) is **.gitconfig**

Comment: Hi @jszakmister, bad news, git aliases cannot work on Ubuntu. Error message: `fatal: While expanding alias 'ldiff': 'bash -l -c 'git diff -U0 $@ | diff-lines' -': No such file or directory`

Comment: Is bash installed?  Ubuntu has switched to using dash by default, and you'll want to be using bash.

Comment: Oh yes, it's dash `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 19 00:49 /bin/sh -> dash*`. I changed the alias as `ldiff = !bash -c '. ~/.marslo/.marslorc && git diff -U0 "$@" | diff-lines' -`, and it works. Thansk!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an alias:

1. Put your code into a script,
2. Name the script `git-ldiff`,
3. Use `chmod +x script` to make it executable, and
4. Put the script in a directory that's in your PATH.

Now, when you type `git ldiff`, git will find and run your scipt.

Comment: Hi @Adam, thanks for your comment. However, I don't want create scripts file alone (even if I knew this way works). I have much function in my `.bashrc`, it's not convenient to manager them. And my PATH will be pretty long..