# How to identify line modifications separately from deletions in git log

Tags: git

In a certain file, I need to count the exact no of lines being **Modified** from one commit to another. If I do a `git log` it indicate me something like this,

> 10    10  modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml 2    2   pom.xml
>
> 4 4   pom.xml
>
> 1 0   modules/distribution/pom.xml
>
> 1 1   pom.xml
>
> 1 1   pom.xml
>
> 10    8   pom.xml
>
> 29    28  modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml 175  4   pom.xml

up to the second line of

> 1 1 pom.xml

can be easily understood, but  from then how do we know for sure that they are just modifications or deletions.
For example,

> 29 28 modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml 175 4 pom.xml

how do we know which is correct from

1. 29 new additions and 28 separate deletions
2. 28 modifications and 1 new addition

is there any options to be used with the `git log` or is there any other way? thanks in advance

Comment: Git *does not* classify something as a "modification". In fact, `git diff` is merely providing *instructions*: "if you delete this line, and add this other line, you will change the old file into the new file." If you wish to superimpose additional semantics atop these instructions, Git leaves that to you. That said, Git includes some contributed programs that do attempt similar work, which might be useful to you, e.g., https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved with `git log`, the only way to achieve this is through `git diff` but in it also it does only provide the no of line additions and deletions, there is no way to identify exactly the no of lines modified. This is because `git` provide the `diff` output in the `unified view` as default not in the `context view`. You can learn about unified view from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html#Unified-Format) and context view from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Context-Format.html#Context-Format).

So if we get the output of `git diff` in the context form, the lines that are added, deleted and modified can easily be identified as additions are shown with "+", deletions with "-" and modifications with "!".
For that we need to use the `git difftool`, the following code works

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -c" <commit1> <commit2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `git diff`:

```
git diff --stat <old-commit> <new-commit> -- <filename>
```

e.g.

```
$ git diff --stat a54873b a6addbd -- Foo.cpp
 Foo.cpp | 42 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------
 1 file changed, 35 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
```

Comment: this also give only additions and deletions only, how do we find how many lines have been modified exactly

Comment: Detecting if lines have been "modified" is a much trickier question, because you have to define a threshold for what's considered "modified" - say you completely replace a line in a file, should that be considered a modification or deletion and insertion?

Comment: If we delete a line and write another line in the same place it is a modification, if we delete a line and add anther line in a different location it is a combination of addition and deletion, if we add lines only it is addition. As you can see in [https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/commit/6b7e426836a527ab57d4125aff34c48b7cbda1c1?diff=split] git any how detect the lines which are modified, I need to know how it does it

Comment: And if you remove and insert multiple lines in the same place? I'm not sure why you don't understand this is a hard problem to quantify. You can probably get by with some combination of `wordiff` and looking through https://github.com/github