# git log shows added / removed - is there a way to show modified lines

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

When we use the `$ git log` command, we can see how many lines added / removed for a file.

My question is - is there a way to inspect which lines were modified (neither added nor removed)? Or can only `git diff` do that?

Sort of a philosophical question, since a modified line could simply be considered to be removed then added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when this answer is written, git doesn't have any option to display line numbers and content which was modified in any way.

What you need to do is to write a script for this purpose.
The following answer supplies you with such a script:

[Using git diff, how can I get added and modified lines numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers#12179492)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what your are looking for could be achieved using [`--color-words`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---color-wordsltregexgt) option for `git diff`.