# Get line change count

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to do a git diff, but only get a list of the files changed and lines changed per file. I have this:

```
git diff HEAD..origin/dev --name-only
```

and I get something like this:

```
assets/shell.sh
package.json
```

but I am looking for something like this:

```
assets/shell.sh     33 lines
package.json        5804 lines
```

is it possible to get such a summary?

Comment: Like `git diff --stat`?

Comment: Yeah like that, but against another branch..Maybe `git diff --stat origin/dev`? Can you add an answer?

Comment: I mean `git diff --stat HEAD..origin/dev` – it’s just an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git diff, how can I get added and modified lines numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259851/using-git-diff-how-can-i-get-added-and-modified-lines-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using `git diff --shortstat --numstat`.

It shows added and deleted lines.

The output looks something like this:

```
$ git diff --shortstat --numstat HEAD^^..HEAD
1       1       Jenkinsfile-sciencetest
88      11      README.md
18      15      src/foo.py
1       0       src/bar.py
 4 files changed, 108 insertions(+), 27 deletions(-)
```

For all lines but the last one, the first column is the number of lines added. The second column is the number of lines deleted and the final column is the file name.

The last line provides the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I want to use:

```
git diff --stat
```

which will compare the worktree to the index. If I want to compared the worktree to another branch, I would use:

```
git diff --stat origin/dev
```

and to compare the index/staging area to another branch you would use:

```
git diff --cached --stat origin/dev
```