# is it possible to add a comment to a diff file (unified)?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I wonder if it's possible to add a certain amount of unparsed content to a diff file (unified)  that is ignored as a comment.

One good use of this would be having git diffs augmented with important information such as from which branch is that diff from (especially when using the --full-index option, which merely displays the blob references).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The unified diff starts with two line header:

```
 --- from-file from-file-modification-time
 +++ to-file to-file-modification-time
```

Anything before this header is ignored, so you can add any comment here, for example:

```
 This may be some useful description of this patch that
 will be ignored by the diff/patch utility.
 --- a/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800
 +++ b/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:50.442260588 -0800
 @@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
 -The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
 -The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
  The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
 -The Named is the mother of all things.
 +The named is the mother of all things.
 +
  Therefore let there always be non-being,
    so we may see their subtlety,
  And let there always be being,
```

Git itself uses this space before header for some metadata, for example:

```
diff --git a/foo b/foo
index 59a4d1f..e48dfe7 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
```

Comment: [quilt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766759/what-is-a-quilt-patchset), a patch management tool, is using the space before the header to store its comments.

Comment: Dude, no need to go all Tao Te Ching on me!

Comment: With `git send-email`, you can add those comments with `--annotate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473120/how-to-add-additional-text-when-sending-an-email-with-git-send-email

Answer (score 17):

You can use `#` instead of `-` or `+` in the diff file for inline comments (recognizable by GNU patch), or add a comment at the begining mentioned by @JakubJirutka

```
 This may be some useful description of this patch that
 will be ignored by the diff/patch utility.
 --- a/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800
 +++ b/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:50.442260588 -0800
 @@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
 # comments on the deletion of the two lines
 -The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
 -The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
  The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
 -The Named is the mother of all things.
 +The named is the mother of all things.
 +
  Therefore let there always be non-being,
    so we may see their subtlety,
  And let there always be being,
```

Comment: `git apply` sees this style of comments as a corrupt patch file.

Comment: Emacs’ `diff-mode.el` seems to recognize `#` as a comment introduction character, at least prior to the first diff hunk.

Answer (score 8):

Anything after @@ on the same line is also ignored.

```
 --- a/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800
 +++ b/foo  2002-02-21 23:30:50.442260588 -0800
 @@ -1,7 +1,6 @@ THIS IS A COMMENT THAT WILL BE IGNORED
 -The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
 -The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
  The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
 -The Named is the mother of all things.
 +The named is the mother of all things.
 +
  Therefore let there always be non-being,
    so we may see their subtlety,
  And let there always be being,
```