# Git vs SVN How to diff against tags

Tags: git

With svn and Cornerstone this is trivial, but I can't seem to find a way to do it with Git or sourcetree (Atlassians excellent visual git tool for mac sourcetreeapp).

I need to compare two commits on the same branch that are several versions apart.  Cornerstone lets me pick any version or tag and compare against my working directory but I can't seem to find a way to get sourcetree, or with git diff and filemerge (opendiff) to do this.

E.g.

```
working dir HEAD
change three
change two
change one Tag: works
```

I need to compare `HEAD` and `works` but I can't seem to find a way to do this.  I can't even check out a file from `works` like I can in SVN, it wants to pull the whole repository at that version and wipe out my working directory.  If I could get the files side by side I could run opendiff or another tool.

What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, like so many things - sleep held the answer.  In SourceTree if you Cmd-Click on two different tags the difference panel automatically displays the cumulative delta against those two versions.  It was right in front of me and I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can compared any two commits with `git diff <commit hash1> <commit hash2>`.
2. You can compare a single file in any two commits with `git diff <commit hash1> <commit hash2> -- file/path`
3. You can also check out a file from a particular commit with `git checkout <commit hash> -- file/path`.

Note: You can substitute `<commit hash>` with any tag, branch, etc.

Comment: I should have been clearer, that generates a giant text file jumble  that I can't import into filemerge (opendiff).  I want to be able to view these files side by side.  Since the two files are not exported my visual diff tools don't know what to do with the output from git diff...

Comment: Here are some links that should point you in the right direction.[link1](https://gist.github.com/329690) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program).

Answer (score 0):

You can diff the tags like so:

```
git diff tag1 tag2
```

Answer (score 0):

Run gitk --all

Select the first commit.

Right click the second commit and select "diff this to selected"

Or you can do that in the command line with git diff.

Comment: I had no idea i had `gitk` installed on my mac.  This will work. Not as nice as Cornerstone, but it will get the job done.  Thank you.