# Using git with diffmerge with no prompts and no alias

Tags: git, git-config, diffmerge

On OSX, I'm using diffmerge as my git diffing tool.  Here is my .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
        tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
        cmd = diffmerge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[alias]
        d = difftool --no-prompt
```

If I just use `git difftool` it will prompt me for every single file I want to diff.  To get around this, I created the `git d` alias and added the --no-prompt flag.

Is there any way I can prevent the repeated prompts without having the alias?  I tried inserting `prompt=false` and `prompt = NO` under difftool, as well as moving the --no-prompt flag next to the diffmerge command, but none of these helped.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> moving the `--no-prompt` flag next to the `diffmerge` command

`--no-prompt` is an argument of `difftool` (as I mention in "[How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949242/6309)").
So I confirm it won't work with `diffmerge`.

> I tried inserting `prompt=false` and `prompt = NO` under `difftool`

under a `[difftool]` section directly, that should work (not under `[difftool "diffmerge"]`)

You can see [another approach here](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2010/08/05/visual-difftool-cygwin-git/index.html/), based on wrappers: that can help to debug those commands.

```
git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge-diff.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\"" \"\$BASE\"" \"\$MERGED\""
git config --global difftool.prompt false
git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
git difftool
```