# Difftool for binary files in Git

Tags: git, batch-file, difftool

I have made Git to diff some binary files by copying the files to a directory in the `Temp` folder in Windows using a `.bat` file (or batch script).

The script copies the original file and makes a companion file with extension `.txt` which contains the text representation of the binary file. Afterwards, it writes the contents of the generated file using the command

```
type C:\DOCUME~1\ROGER\CONFIG~1\Temp\roger\file.txt
```

All that is using Git attributes. Now, I need to use the companion `.txt` file to be used in the `git difftool` command instead of the original file. How do I tell Git which files it should use when diffing `.someExtension` files?

I have tried to make another `.bat` file, but the configuration needed in `.gitconfig` seems to run only Linux scripts, not Windows which are the ones I need, because Linux doesn't understand the path given by Git, i.e., `C:\DOCUME~1\ROGER\CONFIG~1\Temp\` when running the copy command `cp`.

This is my `.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "fmbdiff"]
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false
    path = C:/Archivos de programa/Git/cmd/fmbDiffTool.bat
    cmd = \"/c/Archivos de programa/Git/cmd/fmbDiffTool.bat\" \"/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\"
```

So, the questions that might solve the problem are:

- How do I run a .bat file specified in the cmd entry of the difftool in gitconfig?
- Or: How do I get the path of the Windows temporary folder when running the script Git invokes and Linux can understand for copying?
- Or: What am I doing wrong to achieve this?

Comment: I never been able to make .bat script work with difftool in Windows: only bash script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program/255212#255212

Comment: @VonC Ok, what about the bash understading the correct route to my temporary folder in windows? how can I achieve this?, do I have to make a .exe or something instead of the bash?

Comment: Try with bash-like path for Windows: `"/C/Document and Settings\ROGER\CONFIG\Temp\"`: make sure to get the case (lowercase, uppercase) right for said path though.

Comment: @VonC Well, that wouldn't work for my team, I'm making this for at least 10 people, not everyone have the same path, and I wouldn't want them to set that each time for every computer, they also may have multiple accounts in their computers. I think I will go for the .exe file (or maybe a .jar), thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I have summarized that conclusion in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the difftool declares a batch script, which can work with a Windows path like:

```
/c/xxx
```

That is what I did in "[How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949242/6309)" 4 years ago.

But for a more complex script, the easiest way is to make a separate one (`exe` or `jar`, [as you suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117006/difftool-for-binary-files-in-git/17124119#comment24778720_17117006)), and call it from the batch script.

Comment: One more doubt though before I dive into this. Since the new file is going to be executed from a bash, getting the temp directory in there, say a scala .jar, would that get me "/temp" or indeed point to "C:\DOCUM~"?

Comment: @Roger the `exe` called from the bash script should benefit from classic windows path and environment variables.