# Get full path of a Windows SDK tool

Tags: c#

How can I get the full path of an application? For example, I want to get the path of windiff:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\WinDiff.Exe

My desired result is:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin

I tried this, but won't work.

```
        string fileName = "windiff.exe";
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
        MessageBox.Show(f.FullName.ToString());
```

Comment: How do you want to get `FileInfo` if you don't know the path? If you know the path, you don't need to do all that.

Comment: I just want to get the path of an app called windiff.exe
Given that the user doesn't know where it is located.

Comment: You effectively need to search for it, going though the folders and matching the name. Is it what you want?

Comment: I feel that there is something else going on here that would be useful to understand. Why do you need this information? What are you going to do with it? There might be a better way to solve your higher-level problem, if we were know what that problem was.

Comment: @c45207 I needed this information because there is always a possiblity that windiff.exe is placed in different folder, depends on the user's. I am comparing 2 files that when a double click mouse event happens, windiff will run and compare these files. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to find a file in some location, you can use the code below:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("WinDiff.Exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

`files` array will then contain the files that are found. You can then use `DirectoryName` property to get the folder for each file.

Warning though: when using this way on C:\ drive especially, some folders will not be accessible. You should narrow your search.

Comment: Scanning folders is not a good idea. See Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper Class to get exact path

Answer (score 1):

See the other answers for help on recursively enumerating directories looking for "windiff.exe". Also keep in mind that you might find multiple hits, so you'll need some logic to deal with that.

The higher-level problem here seems to be needing to show the user a diff of two files.

I'd approach this by shipping a default diff tool with my application instead of trying to find the Windows SDK on whichever drive it was installed on, assuming it was installed at all. That is the tool I'd use by default. You can write one on your own or you can, perhaps working with the lawyers :-], include an open source tool.

You could also provide the user an option to configure their favorite diff tool. This is the approach taken by many [source](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) [control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program) [systems](http://whyiamright.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/changing-the-diffmerge-program-used-by-visual-studio/).

Answer (score 1):

The installation folder of Windows SDK is set in the registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\InstallationFolder
```

You could check for several versions of Windows SDK by changing v7.1A to v8.0A for example.

This is a code I use for getting to the folder:

```
        var sdkRootPath = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1A", "InstallationFolder", null) as string;
        if (null == sdkRootPath)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find Windows SDK 7.1A installation folder.");

        return sdkRootPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileInfo` is not going to magically find the WinDiff.exe for you somewhere on the hard drive.  It is a utility class that 'Provides properties and instance methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of files' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

You will have to find the file by either having the user browse for it or search the hard drive(s) programmatically.

Here is an example of how to iterate through a directory tree:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Beware, however, not all users appreciate/trust a program that trolls through their hard drive(s) unannounced!