# Is it possible to set diff/merge-tool for a specific file extension in git-extensions?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, labview, git-extensions

I'm just getting started on developing in LabView, it's all new to me.

And i'd like to use git extensions to handle my versioning. Since the source is in a `*.vi` format, I can't use the normal diff tools, the source is binary.

Fortunately, LabView comes with dedicated diff and merge tools which seems to be very helpful. And I can setup TortoiseGit to use these tools on all *.vi files. It's from this how-to:

https://www.labviewhacker.com/doku.php?id=learn:software:github:getting_started

Is there a way to do the same in Git Extensions? I much prefer git extensions over TortoiseGit.. So I'd rather not be forced to use TortoiseGit.

From what I've found, you can only specify a general diff/merge tool, not different ones for different types of files.

Any help would be appreciated, do anyone know how? :)

Answer (score 3):

If the output of the diff tool is text, you can view diffs under standard Git using a combination of `.gitattributes` and `.git/config`. I hope that Git Extensions would respect this setting.

I recommend reading the [Git Attributes chapter of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) for details on setting this up, but the idea should be something like

```
*.vi diff=labview
```

in your repository's `.gitattributes` file, and

```
[diff "labview"]
textconv = labview-diff-tool
```

in your `.git/config`.

If the diff tool does not output text, you may find the top response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program) useful, which discusses using a graphical diff tool.

Comment: The output is a graphical block diagram unfortunately. :/ But I'll look into the link you posted, thanks!

Comment: You can do these commands with some quick command line action, too.  Here is an example I put together for sqlite3: https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/a028bc3b588baaea09ff67f405af2909

Answer (score 3):

Reference: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/configlvcomp_thirdparty/

1. Right-click in any folder (that is not a git project) and select **TortoiseGit** –> **Settings**
2. Click on **Diff Viewer** tab
3. Click **Advanced** -> **Add**

   1. Extension: `.vi`
   2. External Program: 
      `C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\LabVIEW Compare\LVCompare.exe %base %mine-nobdcosm -nobdpos`

      - `-nobdcosm` means do not compare the appearance of block diagram objects.
      - `-nobdpos` means do not compare the size or position of block diagram objects.
4. Repeat for: `.ctl` and `.llb` extensions