# What is the difference between `git diff` and `git difftool`?

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git diff` and `git difftool`?

I see that I can edit the configuration file for git to easily change the external tool used when I invoke `git difftool` and it seems that `git diff` outputs patches to the command line.

Why would I want to use `git diff`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you and WKPlus said, `git difftool` will use an external tool, while `git diff` will show the diff directly in the terminal.

To answer your last question about *when* you would want to use `git diff`, you can think some of these ones :

1. You do not have a GUI, so you can only use a terminal output
2. You do not have an external tool
3. You do not want to launch a "heavy" external tool and just want to quickly check the diff between two versions

Many other example can be imagined, and maybe you will find some of them yourself using git on daily basis.

Comment: Ah, that simple.  I think my problem was expecting something a little more complex.

Comment: actually you can setup `git diff` to run a GUI or other tool... `git config --global diff.external <path_to_wrapper_script>` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/255212/253127

Comment: Why you wouldn't want to do this, and instead set the external tool as the `difftool` rather than `diff` is because the command-line output will show ALL changes in the terminal at once, while the difftools usually only pop open a GUI one file at a time.. if you have a lot of changes to review quickly, the GUI popup is slower, likely requires you to scroll with the mouse, and switching back and forth from the keyboard slows things down even more.

Answer (score 2):

`git difftool` will show you the diff in some tool (for example: vimdiff) and allow you to edit directly.

If you only want to check the changes you just did, I think git diff is more convenient.

A similar question would be "since `vim` can read a file, why would I want to use `cat`?". The reasons are similar.