# Git diff broken in window git bash shell (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, diff, git-diff

I am working under Windows 7, using the github client and sometimes the git bash shell.

I used to configure my git diff tool with Winmerge using the following information:
[How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program/949242#949242)

For an unknown reason, I cannot use the git diff command anymore:

```
$ git diff
error: cannot spawn winmerge.sh: No such file or directory
external diff died, stopping at path/to/a/file
```

*winmerge.sh* is located in a folder accessible from the path from the regular *cmd* shell, but not from the *git bash* shell.

I also tried to reset the git diff config by removing every line relative to *diff* and *difftool* (both in the *~/.gitconfig* file and with the `git config --global --unset` command), but the error message above keep displaying when calling `git diff`.

Any help would be warmly appreciated!

Comment: `git diff` shouldn’t start the difftool but show a diff in the console. I’d suggest reinstalling it.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled github client without success: *git diff* produces the same error...

Comment: Have you read [this documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#External-Merge-and-Diff-Tools)?

Comment: yes but my diff.tool is set to vs11: it shouldn't try to open winmerge.sh right?

Comment: Did you look at the local git config for the repo (`.git/config`)? Maybe something's wrong there.

Comment: I have no reference to *winmerge.sh* neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I had a reference to winmerge.sh in the PATH. Sorry for the bad question!