# git difftool suddenly stopped working / how to troubleshoot?

Tags: git, winmerge

I have set up my `git difftool` to use `winmerge`.  It has been working for quite a while.  But it suddenly stopped working today.  `git difftool` used to invoke `winmerge` on the dirty files one by one, but not today. The command just returned as if nothing happened.  There were no error messages.

I double checked and indeed I have several dirty files (as shown by `git status`)

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot the problem?  Thanks!

**Updated**

Thanks for the suggestion by fabspro.  I made some progress but still
have not been able to resolve the issue.

My original setting for `winmerge` as `difftool` was this (in my `~/.gitconfig` file):

```
[diff]
      tool = winmerge
```

Now I understand that this will direct `git difftool` to use a script

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools
```

on my computer.  I am going to show the contents of this script below.
I believe the contents are in good shape since no one touched it, and
it was working before today.

And then I also tried invoking `WinMerge` directly, so I change
the directives in `~/.gitconfig` to this

```
[diff]
        tool = mywinmerge
[difftool "mywinmerge"]
        cmd = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

This idea came from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337687/1168041

I double checked the path, and I also checked that in
my `git bash` I 
could invoke `WinMerge` directly (without argument --
unlike the config above) using this command:

```
$ /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe
```

Still, I could not get my `git difftool` command to work
(which was working yesterday)

Any more ideas?  Thanks!

**Appendix**

Contents of my `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools`

```
diff_cmd () {
        "$merge_tool_path" -u -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
        return 0
}

merge_cmd () {
        # mergetool.winmerge.trustExitCode is implicitly false.
        # touch $BACKUP so that we can check_unchanged.
        touch "$BACKUP"
        "$merge_tool_path" -u -e -dl Local -dr Remote \
                "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
        check_unchanged
}

translate_merge_tool_path() {
        # Use WinMergeU.exe if it exists in $PATH
        if type -p WinMergeU.exe >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
                printf WinMergeU.exe
                return
        fi

        # Look for WinMergeU.exe in the typical locations
        winmerge_exe="WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe"
        for directory in $(env | grep -Ei '^PROGRAM(FILES(\(X86\))?|W6432)=' |
                cut -d '=' -f 2- | sort -u)
        do
                if test -n "$directory" && test -x "$directory/$winmerge_exe"
                then
                        printf '%s' "$directory/$winmerge_exe"
                        return
                fi
        done

        printf WinMergeU.exe
}
```

Comment: Does winmerge start if you just start it by itself? How about using the command you have configured in your git config?

Comment: Running the command `winmerge` directly in `git bash` did not start.  The error message was: `bash: winmerge: command not found`.  But I do not recall I changed any path environment variables.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I could locate the executable for winmerge in the installed directory for my `git bash`: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools.  In my git config file, I just set `[diff] tool = winmerge`  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, no worries mate!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found my answer -- the problem was a false alarm.  Sorry!

What happened was that I was confused by the exact semantics of `git difftool`.

Like `git diff`, `git difftool` shows the difference between the working directory and *index*, not the *HEAD*.  When I ran my command, I have already staged my changes (i.e. put them into the index), so while there were differences *from the HEAD*, there were no differences *from the index*, hence the silent behavior of the command. The command that I should have used to show the diff is `git difftool HEAD` not just `git difftool`

I guess the moral of this story is this:
If `git difftool` shows nothings, then try `git diff`.  If the latter
also shows nothings, then there probably are no differences, and probably  nothing is wrong with the configuration of `git difftool`

I would like to conclude this answer with the following wonderful picture 
from "[A Visual Git Reference](https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#diff)" that can serve as a good
reminder of the exact semantics of `git diff` vs `git diff HEAD`

[image]

Comment: Well done, glad to hear you got it sorted and thanks for posting back your findings! :)

Comment: `git difftool HEAD` does work the way `git difftool` should have, thanks.

Comment: great troubleshooting and special thanks for the visual in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments, troubleshooting an external tool can be done by checking the basics - is it configured, is the tool working if you start it by itself, is the tool in the system path/is the correct path to the tool configured in the git config.