# git difftool does not launch Beyond Compare

Tags: git, beyondcompare, difftool

I am struggling with git making run Beyond Compare as my difftool.

I'm using "Git For Windows", Windows 7 32 bits and Beyond Compare 4

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
$ git config --list

[diff]
tool = bc3

[difftool "bc3"]
path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe

[merge]
tool = bc3

[mergetool "bc3"]
path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

Now I've read others questions here and there and followed instructions such as :

- Change 'bc3' by other name i.e. 'abc3' or 'beyondcompare'
- The command : git difftool --tool=bc3 MyFile.java
- Changing 'bc3'path in .gitconfig to 'c:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\bcomp.exe'
- Added $LOCAL $REMOTE to path

What I've realized is that it always launches the default diff console viewer/tool (vimdiff if i'm not wrong) although passing the above mentioned parameter '--tool=bc3' or '--tool=anyname', to 'git difftool' command.

Finally, it just works for 'git mergetool' , in this case beyond compare is launched and as you can see the parameters are the same.

If I've forgotten something or more details are needed, please let me know
Thanks

"When I enter the command git difftool"

[image]

Comment: It seems pretty different for merge tool and diff tool. Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program

Comment: See http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows – If it doesn’t work, try the manual configuration shown in the section below for “GitHub for Windows”.

Comment: Once configured, try this instead: `git difftool --tool=bc3 HEAD botnet. java`

Answer (score 2):

To configure Beyond Compare 4 as an external diff tool in Git for Windows 1.9.5, follow the instructions on Scooter Software's [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows) page.

To diff a file in Beyond Compare after you've followed the configuration instructions:

```
git difftool filename.ext
```

If that still doesn't work, verify you have the correct settings in your `c:\users\username\.gitconfig` file:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

If that still doesn't fix it, make sure you don't have a repository specific setting in `.git\config` overriding the global settings.

Answer (score 1):

Write cohfig format always changes.
This works for Windows 10, VS 2019, Git 2.25

```
[merge]
    tool = BeyondCompare4
[diff]
    guitool = beyondcompare4
    tool = beyondcompare4
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    editor = \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --wait
[difftool "beyondcompare4"]
    path = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\"
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    keepBackup = false
[mergetool "BeyondCompare4"]
    path = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\"
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `git config --list` output is bizarre. Mine has name-value pairs and no section headers (irrelevant properties omitted):

```
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.bc3.path=c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3.path=c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe
```

For me, Beyond Compare 3 works fine with `git difftool <filename>`, no strange options. Beyond Compare 4 is very similar.

My git version is almost the same

```
git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0
```

Maybe you set options for another repository; if `git difftool` comes up with `diff -cc` you definitely have not configured Beyond Compare as the default diff tool. Or maybe your `bcomp.exe` is acting up.

Comment: What I paste above was the output of my "config" file. It wasn't exactly the output of the command "git config --list"