# Visual Studio 2015 Git "Failed to start the configured compare tool."

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to run a diff on a file in my project which should be a simple task, and when I select Compare with Unmodified, I get the error:

> Source Control - Git 
> Failed to start the configured compare tool.

I've looked at the .gitconfig file that was auto-generated by VS2015 and as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with it.

```
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
    autocrlf = true
[credential]
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    keepbackup = false
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m
trustexitcode = true
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The setup for a _visual_ diff tool, like the one with which Visual Studio ships, appears to be more complex than adding a line in `.gitconfig`.  Have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program) which discusses the problem.

Comment: It turns out that I had somehow installed two different versions of Git on my machine and it had a hard time deciding on which version to use. Uninstalling both and reinstalling a single version seemed to help.

Comment: Please answer your own question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall all versions of Git on the machine and reinstall the version needed. Seemed to work for me.

Comment: I have same problem. Reinstalling Git didn't help. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 7):

**Restarting Visual Studio** solved the problem for me 
I am using Visual Studio 2019

---

Very General Advice (could or NOT be helpful to solve this specific problem)

1. Update Git
2. Update GitHub extension
3. Update Visual Studio

Comment: If in doubt, just restart visual studio, it's almost as good as the good old reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If reinstalling Git doesn't help, there is another solution that I've found for a specific case.

If your project lies under a sub-directory of the main Git repository directory that has its own Git repository, deleting the repository in the sub-directory will fix the issue. This could be the case if you had a Git repository before and decided you wanted a different repository that had a larger scope than just the project you were working on and didn't delete the old Git repository files.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hours of searching the cause of this problem I found out the following:

- The problem only occurs if I try to compare the changes of a file which is already open in Visual Studio

Solution/Workaround: **Close the file, after that run the diff on that file**