# Using SmartGit diff tool as external git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, smartgit

I want to set my external giff diff tool to the SmartGit so then, typing git diff in a shell, SmartGit diff windows shows up. Is it possible?

I know how to set up an external diff tool. My question is if there is an executable of SmartGit for showing only diff or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program)

Comment: @Robert sorry, my question was not so clear, I just edited it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SmartGit does not provide a diff command line interface, but you can use [SmartSynchronize](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/) which is more or less the same diff tool which SmartGit uses internally.