# How to graphically diff non-textual files (IIB msgFlows or mappings) on Git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git (bitbucket) for source control. I develop on IBM integration bus and some of its files like mappings, message flows, etc..
are best viewed graphically.
(example: https://transformatech.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/blog-localenv-messageflow-v7.jpg)

I was wondering if there is a tool for comparing the changes side by side, displayed in a graphic view, because as text those files aren't so meaningful.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're basically asking how to do graphical git diff on non-textual files?

Comment: Exactly.
Is there a tool/ add-on for that?

Comment: That would be up to whatever application knows how to parse your file.  Git only understands binary blobs (which can only be diffed by their hash) and text files (which are diffed line-by-line).  If your application doesn't have any sort of diff functionality, your best bet would be to open two instances of said application, one viewing the old file and one viewing the new, and compare that way.

Comment: github supports multiple formats for visual diffing, even some 3d formats. some visual formats also have a text based encoding ( svg for example ), and so text diffing can still be helpful to an extend.

Comment: There are many tools to do [visual comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_comparison). Like [this script](http://varya.me/en/posts/image-diffs-with-git/) — it uses `compare` from [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php).

Comment: Hey, 
That is not what I have asked for (it's not a duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer).

Im aware that you can choose another diff tool when comparing in git,
the question is where can I find such tool.

I would like to see side by side the diffrences between the message flows / mapping nodes that has changed (IIB development) as it should be displayed, and not in a textual way.
example for msgFlow: https://transformatech.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/blog-localenv-messageflow-v7.jpg