# Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool?

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, msysgit

I've tried msysGit and Git on Cygwin. Both work just fine in and of themselves and both run gitk and git-gui perfectly.

Now how the heck do I configure a mergetool? (Vimdiff works on Cygwin, but preferably I would like something a little more user-friendly for some of our  Windows-loving coworkers.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866262/p4merge-error/867165#867165

Comment: Git Extensions has a git UI that has a pretty good, and windows user friendly, merging tool.

Comment: Looks like you need TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

To follow-up on Charles Bailey's answer, here's my git setup that's using [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools) (free cross-platform 3way merge tool); tested on msys Git (Windows) install:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'
```

or, from a windows cmd.exe shell, the second line becomes :

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

The changes (relative to Charles Bailey):

- added to global git config, i.e. valid for all git projects not just the current one
- the custom tool config value resides in "mergetool.[tool].cmd", not "merge.[tool].cmd" (silly me, spent an hour troubleshooting why git kept complaining about non-existing tool)
- added double quotes for all file names so that files with spaces can still be found by the merge tool (I tested this in msys Git from Powershell)
- note that by default Perforce will add its installation dir to PATH, thus no need to specify full path to p4merge in the command

Download: http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools

---

**EDIT** (Feb 2014)

As pointed out by [@Gregory Pakosz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216063/gregory-pakosz), latest [msys git](http://msysgit.github.io/) now "natively" supports **p4merge** (tested on *1.8.5.2.msysgit.0*).

You can display list of supported tools by running:

```
git mergetool --tool-help
```

You should see *p4merge* in either *available* or *valid* list. If not, please update your git.

If *p4merge* was listed as *available*, it is in your *PATH* and you only have to set *merge.tool*:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

If it was listed as *valid*, you have to define *mergetool.p4merge.path* in addition to *merge.tool*:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path c:/Users/my-login/AppData/Local/Perforce/p4merge.exe
```

- The above is an example path when p4merge was installed for the current user, not system-wide (does not need admin rights or UAC elevation)
- Although `~` should expand to current user's home directory (so in theory the path should be `~/AppData/Local/Perforce/p4merge.exe`), this did not work for me
- Even better would have been to take advantage of an environment variable (e.g. `$LOCALAPPDATA/Perforce/p4merge.exe`), git does not seem to be expanding environment variables for paths (if you know how to get this working, please let me know or update this answer)

Comment: Hmm - trying this out - the first config works fine, the next just displays the help text for git config. Not sure why.

Comment: Got it - those single quotes look suspect to me. Just double this up and they work.

Comment: setting `mergetool.p4merge.cmd` will not work anymore since Git has started trying to support p4merge, see `libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib` . instead it directly uses `mergetool.p4merge.path`

Comment: Had to make the second command `git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\""` on my system

Comment: Had to put the full path and escape double quotes: `cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"`

Comment: I added `p4merge.exe` to my PATH, but still had to specify the fully qualified directory location. Also, The escaping of double quotes (or having any at all) wasn't working for me. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217994/881224) worked just fine for me.

Comment: This did it for me: `git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd '"C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge" $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'` on Windows 7 machine

Comment: I got the error: **p4merge.exe: command not found**. _git_ somehow did not read the global path correctly. Solution: Replace `p4merge.exe` with `c:/progra~1/perforce/p4merge.exe`. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: Damn, only @DanielPatz's solution worked in this entire thread.

Comment: @subkamran I added a new section for the current msys git; can you confirm that it works for you? (you should delete mergetool.p4merge.cmd and define mergetool.p4merge.path instead)

Comment: Note that the Git from Windows doesn't really work, but the Git from Cygwin (e.g. installed via apt-cyg) does.

Comment: Just in case, when you are doing this on Windows, add quotes to the p4merge path, something like this:
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path "c:/Users/my user/AppData/Local/Perforce/p4merge.exe"
My user name has one space and it caused some trouble configuring the tool.

Comment: I posted an helper scripts that irons out few defects when integrating Git and P4Merge: http://pempek.net/articles/2014/04/18/git-p4merge/

Comment: Since P4Merge is not a Cygwin application, for Cygwin environments you'll need to use `cygpath` to avoid invalid file errors. For some more detail, see my answer posted **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551253/git-diff-tmp-file-invalid-on-windows-when-using-external-program-on-windows-7/26297369#26297369)**

Comment: For Git Extensions on win 8 full story was: 1. as @DanielPatz suggested: git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd '"C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge" $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED' AND 2. Go to Tools -> Settings -> Git Config. Press Suggest button near Mergetool command. Press Apply

Comment: So for Git Extensions on Windows 8 gui only path should be: 1. Install P4Merge 2. In Git Extensions go to Tools -> Settings -> Git Config 3. Choose p4merge in Mergetool dropdown. Press Suggest button near Mergetool command. Press Apply

Comment: Make sure you're using correct quotation, as I needed to adjust for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217994/3543437

Comment: Bounced around a lot on SO looking for the answer to my problem on this one. As of April, 2016, the Perforce installer automatically adds ```C:\Program Files\Perforce\DVCS\``` to your path. I had to drop the ```DVCS\``` from that entry to catch p4merge.exe in my path. THEN I had to snoop around SO to find a valid config for my Windows 7 MINGW64 setup: ```git config --global merge.tool p4merge``` and ```git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'``` did the trick and now I am up and r unning!

Comment: p4merge seems introduces encoding issue. anyone found a fix? in settings i changed it to utf-8 but nothing changes.

Comment: I don't really understand why, but `git mergetool --tool-help` does not show `p4merge` as available, even after setting the `.path`, but it still works.

Answer (score 90):

setting mergetool.p4merge.cmd will not work anymore since Git has started trying to support p4merge, see libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib.so we just need to specify the mergetool path for git,for example the p4merge:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path 'C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe'
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Works with Beyond Compare 3 as well.  Just use the path to BComp.exe instead.  Thanks!

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but I can't get that path to work. I'm a bit confused about how the path is supposed to be escaped given the interplay of cmd/msys... *EDIT* Switching to double quotes fixed it!

Comment: Thank you Gitninja ! Note that you can type this into Git Bash, but if you use command Prompt you must change the single quote to the double quote

Answer (score 63):

I'm using Portable Git on WinXP (works a treat!), and needed to resolve a conflict that came up in branching. Of all the gui's I checked, [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) proved to be the most transparent to use.

But I found the instructions I needed to get it working in Windows in [this blog post](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1192/setup-git-on-windows-to-use-kdiff3-as-its-mergetool/), instructions which differ slightly from the other approaches listed here. It basically amounted to adding these lines to my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3

[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/YourPathToBinaryHere/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
```

Working nicely now!

Comment: on my Win7 PC, I had to use `path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\KDiff3\\kdiff3.exe` (notice the double back slashes)

Comment: I got an error like this "The diff tool meld is not available as 'D:\software\melddiff\Meld.exe'"

Comment: Do you know if there is a difference with the order where each section is added. I mean, if [merge] would be after [mergetool]?

Answer (score 20):

Under Cygwin, the **only** thing that worked for me is the following:

```
git config --global merge.tool myp4merge
git config --global mergetool.myp4merge.cmd 'p4merge.exe "$(cygpath -wla $BASE)" "$(cygpath -wla $LOCAL)" "$(cygpath -wla $REMOTE)" "$(cygpath -wla $MERGED)"'
git config --global diff.tool myp4diff
git config --global difftool.myp4diff.cmd 'p4merge.exe "$(cygpath -wla $LOCAL)" "$(cygpath -wla $REMOTE)"'
```

Also, I like to turn off the prompt message for difftool:

```
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Answer (score 19):

`git mergetool` is fully configurable so you can pretty much chose your favourite tool.

The full documentation is here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html

In brief, you can set a default mergetool by setting the user config variable `merge.tool`.

If the merge tool is one of the ones supported natively by it you just have to set `mergetool.<tool>.path` to the full path to the tool (replace `<tool>` by what you have configured `merge.tool` to be.

Otherwise, you can set `mergetool.<tool>.cmd` to a bit of shell to be eval'ed at runtime with the shell variables `$BASE, $LOCAL, $REMOTE, $MERGED` set to the appropriate files. You have to be a bit careful with the escaping whether you directly edit a config file or set the variable with the `git config` command.

Something like this should give the flavour of what you can do ('mymerge' is a fictional tool).

```
git config merge.tool mymerge
git config merge.mymerge.cmd 'mymerge.exe --base "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -o "$MERGED"'
```

Once you've setup your favourite merge tool, it's simply a matter of running `git mergetool` whenever you have conflicts to resolve.

The p4merge tool from Perforce is a pretty good standalone merge tool.

Answer (score 11):

For beyond compare on Windows 7

```
git config --global merge.tool bc3
git config --global mergetool.bc3.path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe"
```

Comment: I used these commands but I'm using WinMerge instead of Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that newer git versions support p4merge directly, so

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

should be all you need, if p4merge.exe is on your path. No need to set up cmd or path.

Comment: This is key. After installing p4merge and setting the mergetool.p4merge.path to the exact location, it still did not work. Adding the installation folder to the path did work.

Answer (score 6):

I found two ways to configure "**SourceGear DiffMerge**" as difftool and mergetool in github Windows.

The following commands in a Command Prompt window will update your .gitconfig to configure GIT use DiffMerge:

```
git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd 'C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe  \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"'

git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd  'C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe  -merge  -result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"'
```

[**OR**]

Add the following lines to your .gitconfig. This file should be in your home directory in C:\Users\UserName:

```
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe -merge -result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Answer (score 5):

As already answered here (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)), mergetool is the command to configure this. For a nice graphical frontend I recommend [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (GPL).

Answer (score 4):

I had to drop the extra quoting using msysGit on windows 7, not sure why.

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this through cygwin, you may need to use cygpath:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge `cygpath -w $BASE` `cygpath -w $LOCAL` `cygpath -w $REMOTE` `cygpath -w $MERGED`'
```

Answer (score 3):

Bah, this *finally* worked for me (Windows 7 + Cygwin + TortoiseMerge):

In .git/config:

```
cmd = TortoiseMerge.exe /base:$(cygpath -d \"$BASE\") /theirs:$(cygpath -d \"$REMOTE\") /mine:$(cygpath -d \"$LOCAL\") /merged:$(cygpath -d \"$MERGED\")
```

Thanks to previous posters for the tip to use cygpath!

Answer (score 3):

i use an app called WinMerge ( http://winmerge.org/ )
info from their manual ( http://manual.winmerge.org/CommandLine.html )

this is the bash script i use from the `mergetool` directive via `.gitconfig`

```
#!/bin/sh
# using winmerge with git
# replaces unix style null files with a newly created empty windows temp file

file1=$1
if [ "$file1" == '/dev/null' ] || [ "$file1" == '\\.\nul' ] || [ ! -e "$file1" ]
    then 
       file1="/tmp/gitnull"
       `echo "">$file1`
fi
file2=$2
if [ "$file2" == '/dev/null' ] || [ "$file2" == '\\.\nul' ] || [ ! -e "$file2" ]
    then 
       file2="/tmp/gitnull"
       `echo "">$file2`
fi
echo diff : $1 -- $2
"C:\Program files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub -dl "Base" -dr "Mine" "$file1" "$file2"
```

basically the bash accounts for when the result of the diff in an empty file and creates a new temp file in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add these options too:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4mergetool
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'
git config --global mergetool.p4mergetool.trustExitCode false
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

Also, I don't know why but the quoting and slash from Milan Gardian's answer screwed things up for me.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to use gvim as their diff tool on TortoiseGit, then this is what you need to enter into the text input for the path to the external diff tool:

```
path\to\gvim.exe -f -d -c "wincmd R" -c "wincmd R" -c "wincmd h" -c "wincmd J"
```

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) 3-way git mergetool configuration in Windows environment (`~/.gitconfig`)

**Cygwin**

```
[mergetool "ideamerge"]
     cmd = C:/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/JetBrains/IntelliJ\\ IDEA\\ Community\\ Edition\\ 14.1.3/bin/idea.exe merge `cygpath -wa $LOCAL` `cygpath -wa $REMOTE` `cygpath -wa $BASE` `cygpath -wa $MERGED`
[merge]
     tool = ideamerge
```

**Msys**

```
[mergetool "ideamerge"]
cmd = "/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/JetBrains/IntelliJ\\ IDEA\\ Community\\ Edition\\ 14.1.3/bin/idea.exe" merge `~/winpath.sh $LOCAL` `~/winpath.sh $REMOTE` `~/winpath.sh $BASE` `~/winpath.sh $MERGED`
[merge]
 tool = ideamerge
```

The ~/winpath.sh is to convert paths to Windows on msys and is taken from [msys path conversion question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15434571/535610)

```
#! /bin/sh                                                               

function wpath {                                                         
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then                                                 
        echo "$@"                                                        
    else                                                                 
        if [ -f "$1" ]; then                                             
            local dir=$(dirname "$1")                                    
            local fn=$(basename "$1")                                    
            echo "$(cd "$dir"; echo "$(pwd -W)/$fn")" | sed 's|/|\\|g';  
        else                                                             
            if [ -d "$1" ]; then                                         
                echo "$(cd "$1"; pwd -W)" | sed 's|/|\\|g';              
            else                                                         
                echo "$1" | sed 's|^/\(.\)/|\1:\\|g; s|/|\\|g';          
            fi                                                           
        fi                                                               
    fi                                                                   
}                                                                        

wpath "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

For kdiff3 you can use:

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false

git config --global diff.guitool kdiff3
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false
```

Answer (score 0):

To setup p4merge, installed using chocolatey on windows for both merge and diff, take a look here:
https://gist.github.com/CamW/88e95ea8d9f0786d746a

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems opening p4merge from SourceTree look for you local configuration file named **config** under MyRepo.git and delete any merge configuration.
In my case it was trying to open Meld which I just uninstalled