# p4merge error [GIT]

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4, p4merge

I am trying to use p4merge with git but I am getting:

**Error starting p4merge: "path/myFile" is (or points to) an invalid file** (this lists the BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE, and standard version of the file).

Git tells me about the conflict then it asks if I wanna start the mergetool configured (p4merge) and then I get the error above.

Additional note: it happens with any file!

Any clue about what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe include your section in .gitconfig where you configure the merge tool and the full error message? Do you have spaces in a filename or something?

Comment: nope no spaces in filename - i configured git using this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git diff tmp file invalid on windows when using external program on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551253/git-diff-tmp-file-invalid-on-windows-when-using-external-program-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This worked for me using msysGit on windows 7:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'
```

Not sure why but the quoting screwed things up for me.

Comment: Switched from one Win 8 machine to another, both using git bash and had to do this also, thanks!

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned that I use Powershell, so I'm not sure on about cmd.exe.

Comment: I used `git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd '"C:\Install Dir Has Spaces\p4merge.exe" $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'`

Comment: On windows command prompt, second command failed saying wrong usage. So I executed that on git bash and it worked.

Comment: I did this in Mac terminal and now I get this error: 'p4merge: command not found'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Engin make sure p4merge is available in your path.

Comment: @MikeGlenn, Thank you! You are the first person to share a valid config for my MINGW64 install on Windows 7. Been pulling my hair out for the past 30 minutes.

Comment: @Michael: I had to invert the quotes like so to make it work: `git config --global mergetool.p4mergetool.cmd "'C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe' $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED"`

Answer (score 9):

You will [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences/862920#862920) my config for DiffMerge or KDiff3.

Based on that, I would recommend for p4merge:

```sh
git config --global merge.tool merge
git config --global mergetool.merge.cmd "merge.sh \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" \"$PWD/$MERGED\""
```

and `merge.sh` being a wrapper (copied in a directory referenced by your `PATH` environment variable), able to take into account the case where no `BASE` exists.
(when a file is created in two different branches being then merged, there would be no common ancestor for that file)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Passing the following parameters to mergetool:
#  local base remote merge_result

alocal=$1
base=$2
remote=$3
result=$4

if [ -f $base ]
then
    p4merge.exe -dl "$base" "$alocal" "$remote" "$result" 
else
    p4merge.exe -dl "$result" "$alocal" "$remote" "$result" 
fi
```

You may note:

- the use of `PWD` in the config of the merge
- the use of "`merge`" as name of the merge.tool name (since the actual tool is called in the `merge.sh` script, where you can switch between any number of merge tool you want)
- the use of double quotes around `$base`, `$alocal`, `$remote`, `$result` within the script
- the conditional path for calling the tool, based on the existence of a "base" file.
- the need to always have 3 files to merge as parameters (even when 'base' does not exist...)

---

Just tested it (it turns out, you can [download and install only p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/component.html) -- section Client/Visual Merge Tool --, even if you do not have any other P4 product installed).

With the settings describe above, MSysGit1.6.3, DOS session or Git bash session:
It just works<sup>TM</sup>.

---

Update **msysgit 1.7.x**

[Benjol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11410/benjol) mentions in the comments:

> **p4merge is now supported natively by msysgit**.
>
> This means you can just do:

```sh
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
# and I recommend 
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

Comment: You've got "merge.sh twice in the second line of your first code block, but with that corrected, everything works. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this again on a new machine. Seems to me that if you set the config from bash, the `$PWD` and `$LOCAL` variables get expanded in the config file. I had to go and edit the `%USERPROFILE$\.gitconfig` file manually. Maybe an error on my part, but just in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: @Benjol: interesting, I will test it again also. Was your new machine different from your first tries? (newer Os?)

Comment: @VonC, Vista, yes. Another tweak which may be worth mentioning is `keepBackup = false` (.orig files drive me crazy)

Comment: Note: according to the 3rd comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool/436040#436040), p4merge is now supported natively by msysgit. I'm not sure since which version. This means you can just do `git config --global merge.tool p4merge` (and I recommend `git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false`)

Comment: @Benjol: Thank you for the information, I have included it in the answer.