# Why can't I use TortoiseMerge as my git merge tool on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, user-interface, mergetool, tortoisemerge

I'm trying to perform my first Git merge ever (exciting!), but can't get Git Gui (0.13.GITGUI from Git 1.7.4.msysgit.0) to recognize TortoiseMerge (1.6.11.20210 x64) on Windows 7.  Based on [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool/436040#436040), I've made the following configuration changes:

```
$ git config --global merge.tool tortoisemerge
$ git config --global mergetool.tortoisemerge.cmd 'TortoiseMerge.exe -base:"$BASE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -merged:"$MERGED"'
$ git config --global --list
...snip...
merge.tool=tortoisemerge
mergetool.tortoisemerge.cmd=TortoiseMerge.exe -base:"$BASE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -merged:"$MERGED"
$
```

Unfortunately, when I start Git Gui and attempt to "Run Merge Tool", I receive the error `Unsupported merge tool 'tortoisemerge'`.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?  Here's the relevant sections of my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
        tool = tortoisemerge
[mergetool "tortoisemerge"]
        cmd = TortoiseMerge.exe -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\"
```

**Update**

TortoiseMerge works fine with the above config when running `git mergetool` from the command line.  It seems that only Git Gui has problems with it.  :-/

Comment: Is `TortoiseMerge.exe` in your path?  Have you tried specifying the full path?

Comment: @Ben — It is indeed in my path, and specifying the full path doesn't seem to have any effect.  :-/

Comment: Do you have any space in the files you want to merge?

Comment: @VonC — In the file names?  No.

Comment: @Ben: ok, I was just checking if it has anything to do with http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=479#makechanges and the TortoiseMerge request at http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=2606031

Comment: @VonC — You got my hopes up with that one! Note of the paths within the repo had spaces, but an ancestor folder did.  Moved the repo to a higher folder so that there weren't any spaces anywhere in the paths, but no change. Tried every permutation of arguments, quoting, and `cmd /c` suggested in that issue, and even tried upgrading Git and using `mergetool.tortoisemerge.path` instead of `.cmd`, all to no avail.  :-(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you have the latest git, run this command line once:

`git config merge.tool tortoisemerge`

**Important:** Do not add a `.exe` extension to the command.

If that fails, or if you want to add a different merge tool that git doesn't know about, do this:

Open one of the following in an editor:

- 64-bit git: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-gui\lib\mergetool.tcl`
- 32-bit git: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share\git-gui\lib\mergetool.tcl`

Add something like this to mergetool.tcl:

```
tortoisemerge {
    set cmdline [list TortoiseMerge.exe -base:"$BASE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -merged:"$MERGED"]
}
```

Put the new tortoisemerge entry above this other code:

```
default {
        error_popup [mc "Unsupported merge tool '%s'" $tool]
        return
}
```

**Bonus example:**

To use SourceGear diffmerge, add this to mergetool.tcl:

```
diffmerge {
    set cmdline [list "C:/Program Files (x86)/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe" --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE]
}
```

Comment: Well, I'll be darned.  Two years on and we've finally got a solution for this one!

Comment: I have the latested git-for-windows 2.12.2 install on a 64 bit windows, but the tortoisegitmerge.exe is not in the PATH, so both the updated answer and the outdated answer does not work. Both reported: Unsupported merge tool 'tortoisemerge'. While, my tortoisegit is install in the `E:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe`. So, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perfectly comment. Work very well!

Comment: It's disappointing that `git gui`'s mergetool.tcl doesn't support `mergetool.$tool.cmd` :(

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
[merge]
tool = tortoise

[mergetool "tortoise"]
cmd = "TortoiseMerge.exe" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"
```

Source: http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/getting-git-to-use-tortoisemerge/

Comment: Same problem, I'm afraid.  (Though now the error is `Unsupported merge tool 'tortoise'`, of course.)

Comment: Had to put the full path and escape double quotes: `cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseMerge.exe"\" -base:"$BASE" -theirs:"$REMOTE" -mine:"$LOCAL" -merged:"$MERGED"`

Comment: I had a problem with the files, which have spaces in their names. And this syntax can workaround problem: `cmd = \""c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe"\" -mine \"$REMOTE\" -base \"$LOCAL\"`. This works for TortoiseGitMerge, not TortoiseMerge

Answer (score 6):

For the case that I was working on, the mergetool was already set to tortoisemerge, but it could not find it.

Providing a fully qualified location worked in Windows:

```
git config --global mergetool.tortoisemerge.cmd "\"C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseGit\\bin\\TortoiseGitMerge.exe\" -base:\"$BASE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -merged:\"$MERGED\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try typing `TortoiseMerge.exe` from the command line to make sure it's in the path. If not add it via My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables:Path.

Then from command prompt configure it via the following commands

```
git config --replace --global diff.tool tortoisemerge
git config --replace --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd "TortoiseMerge.exe -base:\"$BASE\" -theirs:\"$REMOTE\" -mine:\"$LOCAL\" -merged:\"$MERGED\""
git config --replace --global difftool.prompt false
```

To use it from the command prompt, type `git difftool` from your within your git working directory.

It shows the files one at a time so you're still better off installing TortoiseGit which makes things easier to handle, even if just for the diff part.

Comment: How can I open GUI based tool to merge all conflict files from Git cmd?

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears resolved in the latest git (I have `git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1`).

```
C:\git\build>git mergetool

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff

C:\git\build>git config merge.tool tortoisemerge

C:\git\build>git mergetool
No files need merging
```