# Using p4merge as mergetool

Tags: git, git-merge, mergetool

I have been trying to setup p4merge as mergetool for my command line git. I followed [instructions here](https://gist.github.com/henrik242/1510148) but I can't get it to work. All of my following commands drop me into the commandline merge and not the visual tool.

```
git mergetool
git mergetool --tool=p4merge
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What does the global git config look like?

Comment: Show `[merge]` section from .config file

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819263/git-gui-mergetool-tortoisemerge-wrong-file-path

Comment: Which OS are you on? If we would knew that we could guide you through the setup