# Git Merge Use Set Default Base

Tags: git, merge, tortoisemerge

I have two git branches. They've both been undergoing development separately. When I do a do a `git mergetool` to use Tortoisemerge to resolve some merge conflicts, I get this error:

```
Tortoisemerge cannot be used without a base.
```

Perhaps I'm missing something in the git docs. Nothing I've seen seems quite like what I want to do:

> Perform a git merge. In the case of a normal file conflict with no
>   BASE that git can figure out by default, just use the local version of
>   the file as the BASE.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the way you're calling tortoise merge.

Take a look at: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190188/why-cant-i-use-tortoisemerge-as-my-git-merge-tool-on-windows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232659/using-git-tortoisemerge-failing-to-load-file-into-tortoisemerge-because-of-sp)

They both solve the same issue ;-)

Just in case:

---

create a CMD file which will launch TortoiseMerge:

```
TortoiseMerge.exe -base:%1 -mine:%2 -theirs:%3 -merged:%4
```

And set up your mergetool in .gitconfig:

```
[merge]
    tool = mytool
[mergetool "mytool"]
    cmd = cmd /C tortoiseMerge-git.cmd "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

---

Cheers,

LEslie

Comment: The cmd wasn't executing on my env in git bash. You can fiddle with it if you really really want to use tortoisemerge in your env. This probably works in the general case, so I'm upvoting it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong.

The thing that worked for me was to use a different merge tool.

People from the future: don't use tortoisemerge. Use meld if you want a gui, or vimdiff if you hate your mouse.