# Workaround or git hook to make git recognize archives of text files

Tags: git, hook, archive, githooks

Is there a way to work with text files inside archives with git without persistently unpacking them?

Presumably to make git to think of archives like directories, with the means of git hooks or other comfortable way.

(I was thinking about mount points on both Win32 and Linux but I'm not sure if that could be made convenient, because each file should be individually mapped as I see it now.)

One application would be that git could work nicely with, say, ODT files. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to read [Pro Git's Diffing Binary Files](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html) sub-section. They give an example about diffing MS Word files, I think you would be able to work with it - maybe combining it with `oodiff` like [VonC said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443603/641451).

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because one of the main points of Git is to be *fast*, and that (working with, that is diff'ing, merging, branching with text files within archives) is not.

For ODT documents in particular, there has been [some proposals](http://alecthegeek.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/git-and-openoffice-org/), but the main one is to differ to a specialized tool for action like merging (like [`xmerge`](http://www.openoffice.org/xml/xmerge/) or [`oodiff`](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~moy/opendocument/)).
(That, or using [pure text-based format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795574/6309))