# Diffing a .ttx file in git

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to diff a .ttx file (bilingual .xml translation file with source (English) strings and target (Spanish) strings and a ton of metadata) with git and it's treating it as a binary so it won't read out the diff, other than what file I changed. I added "*.ttx txt" to my .gitattributes file and still not behaving the way I wanted. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `git diff -a foo.ttx` ? The `-a` argument to `git diff` forces `git` to treat all files as text.

Comment: @Tuxdude that didn't work--just a bunch of garbled characters in my Git Bash window. I did however answered my own question. These files are encoded UTF-16LE and git treats these as binary. Files encoded UTF-16 encoding are most easily diffed with an external diff tool. I use p4merge becuase it's free and easy to set up. [link](https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372) on Mac and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool) for windows.

Comment: @user2347638 Than formulate this as an answer and accept it. Stackoverflow practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are encoded UTF-16LE and Git treats them as binary. Files encoded UTF-16 are most easily diffed with an external diff tool. I use p4merge because it's free and easy to set up.