# p4merge and Git 1.8.3

Tags: git, mergetool, p4merge

How can I config `git` to use `p4merge` as my `mergetool`?

Next is my current situation:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

$ git mergetool

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff
No known merge tool is available.
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/436040/116923) shows you how to do it.

Comment: I have tried it before. It caused my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just posted an article that explains how to integrate Git with P4Merge along with a launcher script that irons out few discrepencies: http://pempek.net/articles/2014/04/18/git-p4merge/

Comment: After having tried several previous demo examples this is the example that worked best for me.

Answer (score 25):

To install `p4merge` and set it as `git`'s `difftool` & `mergetool` on a Linux machine (**Ubuntu 16.04**) I did the following:

1. Go to the [Downloads page](https://www.perforce.com/downloads) of Perforce website, and in the search bar write: `p4merge`.
2. Chose the p4merge for Linux platform and download it (note that you can skip the registration).
3. Once downloaded extract it and copy the contents of the folder to a new folder `/opt/p4merge`:

   a) `gunzip p4v.tgz`

   b) `tar xvf p4v.tar`

   c) `sudo mkdir /opt/p4merge`

   d) I have downloaded it to `/home/guya/Downloads` and the "extracted" p4merge folder was (08/19) ***p4v-2019.1.1830398***, so in my case the command was:

   `sudo mv /home/guya/Downloads/p4v-2019.1.1830398/* /opt/p4merge`
4. Create a symbolic link to the `p4merge` executable with the command:`sudo ln -s /opt/p4merge/bin/p4merge /usr/local/bin/p4merge`
5. Add the following commands to `git`'s "global config settings" so `p4merge` will be used as both `git`'s `difftool` & `mergetool`:

   `git config --global merge.tool p4merge 
   git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path /usr/local/bin/p4merge
   git config --global mergetool.prompt false`

   `git config --global diff.tool p4merge
   git config --global difftool.p4merge.path /usr/local/bin/p4merge
   git config --global difftool.prompt false`
6. In order to see diff's (between Working directory to the staging area, for instance) you can now use the command:`git difftool` that will open the p4merge GUI to be used.

NOTE: `git diff` will still work and will display the diffs in the terminal.

Comment: For some reason when I paste those git config -- commands, when I exit and try "git difftool" I get "fatal: bad config line 1 in file .gitconfig"

Answer (score 3):

The article [Installing and Using P4Merge in Git for Windows](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/05/12/installing-and-using-p4merge-in-git-for-windows/) worked for me.

Edit your global .gitconfig and add the following sections (you don't have to worry about where p4merge.exe is located, it was added to your path during the installation):

```
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = "p4merge.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE"
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = "p4merge.exe $BASE $LOCAl $REMOTE $MERGED"
    trustExitCode = true
    keepTemporaries = false
    keepBackup = false
    prompt = false
```

> There is one caveat, in order to run "git difftool' or "git mergetool"
>   you have to first run "git diff" or "git merge" and have a difference
>   or conflict.  The editor will then launch with the correct files ready
>   for editing.