# Missing git difftool for windows git bash

Tags: windows, git, difftool

I want to use difftool as the tool for dealing with git diff's. Specifically, I am used to using Vimdiff on an Linux environment. It doesn't seem that any tools come with git on Windows. I am running a Git Bash and I got the following message:

```
:~/rush$ git difftool

This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
kompare emerge vimdiff
```

What difftools can I use on Windows?

Comment: The question is off topic here (because questions asking for tool recommendations are off topic). That being said, I also recommend BeyondCompare (which is commercial, but definitely worth the price). I've heard of people using p4diff (the diff tool that comes with the free Perforce client) with satisfaction as well.

Comment: You can thank Microsoft for producing an "operating system" where the only thing you can do without installing lots of other software first is play solitaire or Explode the web...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Mah, I did set this up with BeyondCompare and it works! See how to do it here:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs