# Git merge driver is not used

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have two branches b1 and b2 like this:

MyRepo
|- .git
|---|- config
|- .gitattributes
|- D1
|---|- foo.xml

In git\config, I have this configuration:

```
[merge "MyMerger"]
    name = My merger
    driver = MyMerger.exe %B %A %O
```

MyMerger.exe exists in the Path environment variable

Then, in .gitattributes, I have this:

```
/D1/foo.xml merge=MyMerger
```

But when I try to merge B1 and B2 with changes in foo.xml in both branches, it fails:

Auto-merging D1/foo.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in D1/foo.xml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

I also tried to move the .gitattributes in D1 using this configuration:

```
foo.xml merge=MyMerger
```

But it fails too.

What did I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial config works fine as far as you don't have a BOM in your .gitattributes

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must have `merge.tool` and `mergetool` configurations to set a custom merge tool.

Check out this post that gives the exact `git config` commmands you need to run: [Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool)

Comment: Thanks for the reply  
So I now use this config:  

    [merge]  
        tool = MyMerger  
    [mergetool "MyMerger"]  
        cmd = "\"C:\\...\\MyMerger.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\"" 

 
But it does not work better.  

Do I still miss anything?  

Thanks