# How do I view modified files in detail? So I can choose what to include / exclude at file level

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-merge-conflict

Hi guys this is the scenario,

I'm finding it hard to find an easy to understand scenario tp provide a good context so lets use Umbraco CMS as an example...

**Example Context**

Lets say I have a working website using this CMS and it has my updates to some configurations in it, views etc, the site works fine. But 6 months a head theres a new version upgrade to the CMS lets say it's Version X.3 and im on X.1 so when I download the new files from the umbraco website for the upgraded version I need to drop these files on top of an existing umbraco working site.

**Now the question is:**

I know which files were modified by doing a ***$git status*** but is there a way to view what sections in a given file has been modifed so I can then choose what I want to keep and what not (they overrride my custome configuration updates), I've tried pretty much everything even doign the upgrade on a separate branch and trying to merge to an existing with the hope I'd get the conflict resolution to appear but it doesnt...

Is there a way of doing this: choosing of what I want to leave and what i want to remove when no conflict resolution is given?

I have found a tool that allows me to do this choosing between what to leave and what to remove, thanks to an article [umbraco in 24 days](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/upgrading-umbraco-using-git/) (hence why im using the umbraco example, but not really using umbraco)

**This tool allows me to do exactly what I need** (Git Extensions)

[image: See Git Extensions allows you to stage or unstage selected lines! this is exactly what i would like to achieve without the use of this tool]

I'm also wondering can this be done using sourcetree? havent seen a way to, you definately cant do it in Visual Studio (which is the IDE I'm using, or perhaps i havent found a way)

What i would really like to have happen is to get a conflict in git so i can use my IDE to choose what to leave and what to update, when i merge this from a differnt branch it just overrides everything even if i say ***$git merge -X ours UpdatedBranch***

Comment: `git mergetool` may help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool.

Answer (score 1):

> havent seen a way to, you definately cant do it in Visual Studio (which is the IDE I'm using, or perhaps i havent found a way)

Yet, what you describe looks like [Visual Studio merge resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/merging?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)

> - The conflict notification appears. Click the Conflicts link to start resolve file conflicts.

[image: Prompt when there is a merge conflict when you pull a change]

However, this is not your scenario: you seek to add chunk of merged files *even* when there is no conflict.

That would involve telling Git you want to force a conflict: see "[Git - how to force merge conflict and manual merge on selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091756/6309)". It uses a merge drive which merges the file, but exit with status 1.

Comment: Thanks i know what a merge resolution is and I have done it before, the issues is that when the files I'm updating DO NOT show conflict they just override, did you apply a specific merge strategy, what you have shown is what I normally get when i have conflicts, and what I wish I got when I updated the files from the third party update download... see as far as git knows its like me updating the file my self so why would there be a merge conflict when it thinks I have updated the files... If it was as simple as that i wouldnt be posting this.

Comment: @EgliBecerra No problem. I'll delete this answer shortly.

Comment: @EgliBecerra Maybe this would for a conflict, allowing my answer to then, be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091756/6309

Comment: The fact that you went out and sought a possible answer is good and I give you thanks for this, I won't flag your answer as negative. the correct answer would be something where i tell git hey git force conflict for every change that was updated by these files being dropped so i can see what changed, theres also the option in VS "Compare with previous version" that allows me to see the diff and what was updated but what I need is the conflict interface even when theres no "apparent" conflict so i can choose what to keep and what to chuck.

Comment: It wont let me undo my minus score to you, I'll wait a little then remove the down vote

Comment: @EgliBecerra Thank you. I have rewritten the answer to highlight what you actually want, and point to the possible workaround (merge driver) to force the merge conflict.