# tool for solving "trivial conflicts" in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Do you know any tool/switch for git commands which help me prevent conflicts or speed up merges?

Currently I often got "trivial conflicts" such this:

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++=======
+ onClick
+ onWakeup
++>>>>>>> 587f917...
```

I suppose that that is caused by some white-spaces.. this is very easy to solve by human, however it requires a lot of time to resolve all such conflicts.

Is there any tool which can solve this type of conflicts automatically?

---

PS. I am still learning English, however sometimes I am making stupid mistakes. I am doing my best, writing questions and answers in English, however I would be very glad if you will edit my post in case of any mistakes. I promise, your effort will not be wasted.

Comment: See this thread for visual merge tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: I would like to know this as well, it would be good have a tool which solves as many trivial merges as it can, so I have less to process in a visual merge tool.

Answer (score 2):

Run `git-mergetool` to resolve merge conflicts.  See the **[man page here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html)**.  Git has several options for merge tools.  I prefer **[kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)**.  It's open-source, cross-platform, and easy to learn.

Git resolves as many conflicts as it can.  If you get that message, it means git found a conflict that requires human intervention to resolve.

Comment: yes, I understand, but in my opinion it can be quite obvious, that result of this (specific types of) conflict will be removing lines "++<<<<<<< HEAD", "++=======", "++>>>>>>> 587f917... ". I am looking for tool, which will do this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself resolving the same conflicts again, and again, then you probably want to use [git rerere](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html).