# Automerge issue when merging in Webstorm

Tags: git, webstorm

Let's say you've got 2 branches A and B.

I want to merge B into A but it does an automerge.
So I checked out A and then tried

```
`git merge --no-commit B` to turn off automerge
```

But doing it this way, the merge isn't concluded but already happened.
Is there a way to merge only certain lines of code of B into A? 
Preferrably with the webstorm mergetool?

Comment: I just found the following method in webstorm: git->compare with branch. This way of working is ok, but than with a commit (merge) message. Is that possible?

Comment: I recommend you the following

http://stackoverflow.com/a/20256067/568901