# Git merge: is it possible to avoid auto-merge for non fast-forwarded files?

Tags: git, merge

When I do a `git merge` I would like that only the files that can be fast-forwarded (i.e. the files that have changed only on one of the branches being merged since the last common revision) are automerged, while all the other files (that have changed on both branches, even if on different lines) are marked as conflicts. I have looked around but it seems that there is not a "simple" way (e.g. an option to pass to `git merge`) to do that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file) there is a similar question, but not quite this one. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-to-prevent-an-automerge-using-git) there is a very similar question, but it is 4 years old and it has no conclusive answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, "fast forward" is not the right phrase here as it refers to branch label operations, which are based on the commit graph.  The content of any given commit is not controlled by the graph (although certain degenerate graph cases do limit the possibilities for content-changes).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible to do this without using some sort of script (shouldn't be too difficult). I looked for a similar solution a couple months back and I simply ended up disabling the fast-forwarded merge. I think they mention how in some of the questions you added:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `* -merge` in `.git/info/attributes` of the repository where you're performing the merge. This will prevent any auto-merging, introducing merge conflicts instead.

Note that `.git/info/attributes` has the highest precedence of all `.gitattribute` files, so none of those would cancel it out.