# How to disable git automatic merge

Tags: git

I'm working with git and i want to disable git automatic merge on `git pull`  because sometimes it results of code errors since git merges based on line comparison .Is it possible to force GIT to always launch manual merge instead of automatic merge on `git pull`, other words disable git automatic merge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent an automerge using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-to-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)

Comment: already gone through this post , it's not what i'm asking , i'm asking if it's possible to bypass for good the automatic git merge process, the answer provided in the post restrict you to always go through git difftool before doing a git pull, whereas what i need is to disable git automatic merge.

Comment: No, but I'm curious why you would want to.

Comment: Sometimes merges cause errors, and to  have full control of code i need to set a way to make git always run manual merge for developers

Comment: What do you call manual merge?

Comment: means i control the merges, do not let git add code for me

Comment: Do you understand what a merge _is_?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you please elaborate on that point ?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, what do you consider to be "unwanted merges"? As it raises questions about what you understand a merge to be.

Comment: merging doesn't add code semantically and this causes error since git merges by comparing lines and sometimes it happens that git merges code in a bad emplacement which causes errors so i don't want to let this marge of errors that why i want , always and everytime i do a git PULL , git to ask to merge manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess on what you actually want here is to disable merge when there is no possibility to fast forward you current branch to the upstream branch.

By default git behavior is that when your local branch is different from the upstream `git pull` runs merge. Merge in its turn will attempt to fast forward the branch and if it fails (this happens if your local branch is not a direct ancestor of the upstream branch position) it then tries merging it the "usual" way. In this case merge may result in merge conflicts that you'll have to resolve. This is I think is what you mention in your question and what you want to stop happening.

To prevent this situation you can configure `git pull` to only perform merge if fast forward is possible. You can do this by specifying `--ff-only` to `git pull` invocation:

```
git pull --ff-only
```

Or you can make this the default behavior for `git pull` by using `git config`:

```
git config --global pull.ff only
```

Answer (score 3):

From `git pull` manpage:

> git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

So [`git fetch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-fetch) may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like "manual merge".

However, if you want to inspect (and modify) the result of the `merge` before committing it, you can add the [`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---no-commit) command line flag to the [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) command.

Git still does the merge but you can review and correct it (if needed). Then, when you are satisfied how the merged code looks like you can run `git commit` to complete the merge (and the pull).

Comment: That worked quite well for me.