# Is it possible to do git mergetool for *all* changes?

Tags: git, git-merge

I need to merge two branches in Git, but I have to be really careful regarding all files being merged. I need to keep some of them even if they are changed in second branch and sometimes I need to keep a part of them only. The easiest way would be to do a forced merge with mergetool for all files, not only those with conflicts. Is it possible?

Comment: This is pretty easy to do using the GUI on github

Comment: @JoshAdams This does not directly solve my problem, but you may add an answer describing this technique - maybe it will help others :)

Comment: sorry @spook Let me take some screenshots and upload to an answer :) give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

There's this answer [How to prevent an automerge using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-to-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)
that suggests to use a difftool on the two branches before even attepmting to merge. Commit the changes on all the files that you need. Then do a merge.