# Merge conflict issue in git

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I created `TestA` and `TestB` branches from the `TestUAT` branch then made the following changes:

1. Changed some code in `Class A` on `TestA`
2. Commited the changes , created a pull request to merge branch `TestA` with `TestUAT`. It gave no conflicts.
3. Changed some other line of codes in the same `class A` on `TestB`. Committed these changes, created pull request to merge branch `TestB` to `TestUAT`. Here, it got auto-merged without any conflict errors.

My questions are:

1. In which condition will it show merge conflict?

I thought it should show a conflict if the source branch and destination branch both differ from their last code base. 
In the above example, when I perform step 3, the `TestUAT` branch is changed from its previous code base (as i have merged `TestA` with `TestUAT`) and `TestB` has also changed (code changes done in `Class A`). I should have got the merge conflict error for this scenario.

2. How to stop the auto-merge which is happening in this case?

Comment: you might want to check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-do-i-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)

Answer (score 0):

The merging algorithm is much smarter than that and there are also different strategies you can use. You can look here for more information https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

For the auto-merging issue see this thread [How do I prevent an automerge using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-do-i-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)