# Git rebase without auto-merge to override remote branch's code

Tags: git

When I do a `git rebase [remote branch name]`, everything is fine, however, I override some of the code from the remote branch. Since my commits are coming on top of the head of the remote branch's. The rebase process does an `auto-merge` according to the logs.

How do I avoid the auto-merge, or what is the best approach to take in this scenario?

Some context: I forked off someone else's branch and would like to receive their updates. The rebase puts my updates on top of theirs, overriding maybe two lines of code because it `auto-merges`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent an automerge using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-do-i-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)

Comment: What scenario? Unclear why you would rebase onto a remote branch or what you expect the rebase to do. Please state actual purpose, show actual commands, describe desired and actual outcomes.

Comment: Added some context @matt