# Setting diffmerge as visual Git difftool not working

Tags: git, powershell, git-config, github-for-windows, diffmerge

I am trying to configure DiffMerge as my difftool in Git but having no luck. This is the revelent section of my **.gitconfig** file (the other settings not shown are just for the user).

```
[diff]
        tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
        cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Whenever I call `git difftool` from the powershell command line the conflicts are shown directly beneath in the powershell interface, not in diffmerge as intended. I know the settings are being picked up by git because when I inspect the global config I am given the settings from the config file:

```
git config --global --get-all difftool.diffmerge.cmd
"C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\sgdm.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

I am running powershell and not git bash. This is because I installed github for windows which provided powershell as the shell for git so I have not needed to install bash (yet). Git version is 1.7.11.msysgit.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting mixed up with `difftool` and `mergetool`. I needed to be use `mergetool` to resolve conflicts with a visual inteface and save the results. `difftool` only shows you the differences. See [git-mergetool-vs-difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197465/git-mergetool-vs-difftool) for clarification.

I added this section to my `.gitconfig` and called `git mergetool` from the powershell command line instead. Happy days.

```
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe\" --merge --result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = true
    keepBackup = false
```