# Use vscode's 3-way merge tool to combine two branches (or general git refs)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge

I have a complicated merge between branches where git keeps auto-merging files in a way that I don't want.  There aren't a huge number of changes, so really what I would like to do is manually "resolve merge conflicts" between the two branches, even though git isn't detecting any merge conflicts.  Is there anyway to open the vscode 3-way merge tool with one branch on the left, the other branch on the right, and getting a manual combination as the output (on the bottom).  This seems like it would be a simple, and incredibly powerful tool (especially if the left and right can be any pair of git refs, not just branch HEADs).

There are a large number of similar questions on SO for manually merging files ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657009/how-to-merge-all-files-manually-in-git)).  As far as I can tell all of the "answers" are really work-arounds.  e.g. the merge is done normally, but then resetting HEAD so that everything appears as a change.  One exception is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file) which creates a new merge-tool that forces every change into a conflict, which is a little extreme, but looks like it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent an automerge using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-do-i-prevent-an-automerge-using-git) See the answer with `--no-commit`. If you don't want it to automatically create a merge commit, tell it to not do so.

Comment: If you squash branchA on branchB and no commit. You could have something similar.

Comment: Notice: despite what vscode claims it does **not** currently have a 3-way merge tool, it is only 2-way. A proper 3-way merge tool (like [KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3)) have in total 4 panes: common base + destination + contributing as three panes on the top and then a result pane on the bottom.

Comment: @dan1st thanks for pointing that out, but no it does not (and the answers are identical to the question that I linked to.  The KDiff3 answer comes closest, but isn't a viable tool for me.