# Git merge mangles source files

Tags: git

I've run into some strange behavior with git and I was wondering if anyone has any experience with it.  I have two branches, stable and master, that I have merged after resolving conflicts.  Unfortunately, the master branch (which should now reflect all of the changes in stable) will not compile due to the insertion of markup by git.  It looks something like this:

```
>>>>>>> stable
=======
```

Duplicate code will usually appear between the markups, presumably to differentiate between code in the different branches.

Ideas?  Thoughts?  Doinitwrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, that mangling is git's way of showing you what the conflicts are. They are called 'conflict markers'.  When resolving conflicts you need to remove those extra characters as you go along and pick the correct side to keep (old vs new code).

Once you have resolved all the conflicts and removed the extra characters/lines then add and commit those changes to finish the merging of the branches.

Here is tutorial about [basic branching and merging](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html) and another right from the [git manual on resolving conflicts](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge).

Comment: Thanks.  I've never actually merged any conflicts before, so this is new to me

Comment: My pleasure. We all start somewhere and fortunately this is a great place to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than resolving merge conflicts by hand, look at using [git-mergetool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) with [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/).

[image: git merge using meld]

#### See also

- [Painless Merge Conflict Resolution in Git](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html)
- [What's the best visual merge tool for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git)

Comment: That's interesting.  Is there anything out there that's console-based?  Meld looks really cool, but I'm developing in windows with a linux box running git (if that makes any sense at all).

Comment: @danthehat If you're comfortable with it, you could specify vimdiff with `git mergetool -t vimdiff`. If you have a clone of your repository on your Windows box, you could use [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) instead. Another option is to run an X11 server on Windows (such as the [free one from Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/)) to let `meld` run on Linux and display on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That is [How conflicts are presented](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html?#_how_conflicts_are_presented) by Git, or for that matter any other Source Version control system like CVS, SVN, Perforce, Mercurial, Bazaar.