# Is there any way to batch "pretty" format PHP files in a folder?

Tags: php, batch-file, code-formatting

I have a folder of PHP files. The source code to these files is compressed into a few lines with no line breaks or other conventional formatting and is extremely hard to read.

I have found several online tools to make the source readable, but they all do this is one by one:
http://thephppro.com/tools/beautify.php
http://www.prettyprinter.de/

**How to format source code in batch?** Is there any way to accomplish the process of making a folder/subfolder of PHP source code readable more efficiently? Is there any IDE that will format files in batch mode, or another php script/cli tool that I am unaware of which can perform this operation?

Comment: This site is bonkers. "Instead describe the problem and what has been done to solve it". I have a specific problem - here are the tools I tried to use to solve my problem. How is this off topic? Whereas this post is literally just asking for tools https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/)?

Comment: Beautify all files and recreate the dir structure on ./myprogram-beautified/

  php_beautifier -r "*.php" ./myprogram-beautified/

Comment: To add on to @timelf123's post, navigate to the project path - `cd /path/to/project` - then run - `php_beautifier -r "*.php" /path/to/project` - You could also run `php_beautifier -rv "*.php" /path/to/project` to get a verbose output. May need to run as admin/root(sudo)

Comment: Use [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) with atom IDE for Beautify many file formats.

Comment: Please try [PHP-CS-Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/), which is a more up-to-date and powerful tool. Not only beautifying the code, but also fixing it to following PHP code standards. Though it takes a little bit time to get started with.

Comment: I don't know why, it seems to remove .htaccess from result