# git, SourceTree - How to merge interactively?

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way to merge two branches interactively in SourceTree or git? i.e. during merge, can I pick interactively/visually one hunk of file A from one branch and another hunk of file A from another branch and merge them together?

Comment: With git you can just specify an external merge tool, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can do it.
Once the file is committed stand on the file and choose the hunk buttons as displayed in the attached image

[image]