# How to ask git if and where given deleted hunk lives now?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

When merging, I often have modified code that is now "deleted". However it may have been moved somewhere else. How can I find out where?

Example: I change one line in a function `foo` defined in file `A`. Next, I merge with tree that this function is now moved to file `B` (and possibly also changed one line). In `A` the conflict markers say "this hunk was deleted".

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your branch is `mybranch` and the main tree is `master`, you could do `git diff mybranch...master`. This will show you all changes between the two branches using their nearest common ancestor commit as a reference point.

In the diff, you can search for your file to see what happened to it.

For more details see `git help diff`.

Comment: Rather crude, but I must admit it does the job.

Comment: @sevo - heh, that's a pretty good description of git in general.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of visual diff and merge tools which provide better visualization of diffs. These generally can show when a hunk of code was moved rather than deleted.

You use them with [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) and this must be configured with which tool to use. [There's a wide variety available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git#137141). Here's an example using Meld.

[image]

Comment: I think OP is looking for inter-file moves, rather than intra-file.