# how to resolve .pbxproj merge conflict using Atom?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-merge-conflict

If merge conflict is detected in .pbxproj file, which sign means the conflicted source?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdzkn.png)

which of these signs should i delete here?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt taken from this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts)

> Think of these new lines as "conflict dividers". The ======= line is the "center" of the conflict. All the content between the center and the <<<<<<< HEAD line is content that exists in the current branch master which the HEAD ref is pointing to. Alternatively all content between the center and >>>>>>> new_branch_to_merge_later is content that is present in our merging branch.

I would suggest you to use some mergetool which will make your life easier. Here is the [link for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137141/468724)

Or on terminal just run the command `git mergetool` it will open the diff and chose right or left or both. Here is [tutorial for it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJh4ZyjCfeo)